# window.location.replace strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

So I'm having this issue where I lose all my data on the first window.location.replace try (The second time i reload the same page everything seems to work fine)
I have searched around and haven't found anything like this

Here is the code so I can explain my issue more toroughly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
     // Retrieve form data
        var formData = {
            'index'            : $('input[name=user]').val(),
            'password'          : $('input[name=pass]').val()
        };
        //convert formData from JS object to PHP understandable 
        var formData1=jsObj2phpObj(formData);

        var url= 'login.php';
        //sending with post in ajax to register.php
        $.post(url,{formData1:formData1})
         .done(function(data){
            if(!(data["Log_success"])){ 
              alert("Log failed")
              }
            else
              {
               window.location.replace('http://localhost/CPPv2/admin_commented/index.html#home');
               var draw_stringholder="";
               draw_stringholder+=data["user_index"]+data["user_email"];
               document.getElementById("myPanel").innerHTML=draw_stringholder;
               }
          }
```

So what my function does is that it sends data to a PHP page and recieves JSON encoded data back. The first time I submit the form I seem to recieve no network data back (I think it's because of the window.location.replace removing it) but after refreshing the page and submiting the form again everything works fine (The Index and email are written inside myPanel element).

I have tried using window.location / window.location.href ... (I think i tried every other function there is) and they just don't send me anywhere like they're not working at all. The if(!(data["Log_sccuess"])) part always works (so the client - server communication works fine).

It's also important to say that im using JqueryMobile-1.4.4 (also tried their redirect method didn't work)

To sum it up I would like to change my current page link to a other one without losing the server generated data. (Since Im bassicaly staying on the same page just changing the Id part of it). I can fix my issue by refreshing the page after I have logged in (sending server request after log in) but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "url")` instead of `window.location.replace`.

Comment: I tried this but sadly it didn't work it just refreshed the same page, after that If i tried to log in my app would just ignore the prevent default function for some odd reason.

Comment: Add `data-ajax="false"` to form.

Comment: I don't know if anyone is still looking for this but after reading the documentation I found out the solution to my problem.

Instead of window.location.replace I used $.mobile.changePage( "#ulr", { transition: "slideup"} );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of window.location.replace I used $.mobile.changePage( "#ulr", { transition: "slideup"} );